# get property of changed from other method within same class

Tags: php, oop

This is my code. What i want is assigning the property `$a` value in method `set_a()` i need to get the same value within `get_a()` method without calling `set_a()` after object initialized or within `get_a()` and also dont want to pass any parameters to either methods. Is there any other methods do this?

```
class simple
{
    public $a;

    public function set_a()
    {
        $this->a = "ABC"; //need this value in get_a()
    }

    public function get_a()
    {
        echo $this->a; //should referenced from set_a()
    }
}

$foo = new simple();
echo $foo->get_a(); //output should be "ABC"
//or
echo $foo->a; //output should be "ABC"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either initialize your property in class:

```
class simple
{
    public $a='ABC';
    //...
}
```

or do that in constructor:

```
class simple
{
    public $a;
    public function __construct($a='ABC')
    {
       $this->a=$a;
    }
}
```

-the second way is better since it allows you to initialize not only *constant expressions* (complex expressions can not be used in first case). However, if initializing value relies on something too complicated (function calls e t.c.) - you'll need to define desired behavior inside constructor.

See [this reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) for more clarifications of what is allowed in first case.